# how to click all buttons with same class (java)

Tags: java, selenium, button, click, subscribe

i've been trying to click all buttons with the same class.
For example: i want to click all  buttons on the page which have the same class.  I'm not sure if this is the emulator or is there some java code I can put that will allow me to click any button at random? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF")).;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(50);
        while n > 0 {
            button.click();
            n--;

Comment: Please don't post comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Code is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code--

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.className("NameofTheClass"));
    for(WebElement element: list)
    {
         element.click();

    }
```